# Memory debugger for C++ on Windows, able to find leaks

Tags: windows, memory-management

Are there any available programs to manage memory usage, GDI objects? I would like to receive data about the allocation and usage of memory objects in the code. Now I am involved in a project in C ++, Visual Studio, Windows. I faced the problem of leakage. And I can not always find where they appear. I searched myself and found very expensive programs. Is there something free or inexpensive?

Comment: Based on what you've got in your question, what you're looking for is a memory debugger, not a memory usage manager.  The classic FOSS example of such a tool is valgrind, but that unfortunately is essentially UNIX-only.

Comment: I think you have formulated the question more accurately. Thanks for the amendment. Apparently, I need to look for an analogue Valgrind for Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[VLD](https://kinddragon.github.io/vld/) is a good debugger. Easy to use, convenient. You can find a lot of tutorials and videos on YouTube about it. But it doesn't catch GDI-leaks. [Deleaker](https://www.deleaker.com/) can detect them. This is a paid tool that integrates into the Visual Studio development environment. Also it catch handles.
Wikipedia has a list of debuggers for all cases)

Comment: Can you briefly tell how these programs work? Do they show what processes cause leaks? Or show an object that is not deleted?

Comment: It seems that VLD is dead :( According to their github...

Comment: Obviously there are no updates for a long time. This happens sometimes. But as I understand the debugger works fine

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps you have already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) old topic. I want to note that not all debuggers are listed here. There is a good plugin for Visual Studio called PVS studio which just gives more in depth warnings.
I like the standard debugger. Also good leak detection programs are Insure and Deleaker.

Answer (score 3):

Intel Inspector is a good debugger. It works not only with memory. But very expensive in my opinion. More details you can find on the official website.

Comment: Thank. I hope to find something less expensive. But I understand your choice, this should be a good debugger?

Comment: Yes, a big plus is working with threads. But the application has its drawbacks. It is rather slow for me. There are false positives  sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [GDIView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/gdi_handles.html). And i found this program, probably is it better. [Apimonitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor)

Comment: Could you explain a bit about the features of each suggestion and how they comply with the question?

Comment: I heard good reviews about GDIView. Is this program still supported?